# How does someone lock multiple objects in one thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to create a physics engine (just for fun) and I would like it to be multi-threaded.
I understand the basics of a mutex (only one thread can modify the resources it is guarding at a time, they should be at a class level instead of thread level, etc). I would prefer to NOT use atomics for the member variables (so that if I am doing complex operations on them, they will not be changed right in the middle of the execution), or to simply copy the variables (for a hopefully lower memory footprint).

Following this notion, a (simplified) vector class might look like this:

```
class vector
{
    float x_, y_;
    std::mutex guard_;
};
```

If I want to use it, how should they be locked?

```
void foo(vector v1, vector v2)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(v1.guard_);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(v2.guard_);
    // Do stuff with v1 and v2...
}
```

Like this? Will this actually protect both both objects?

TL;DR How should mutexes be locked when there are multiple objects being operated on by the same thread? (Without using atomics or making copies)

Comment: Looks good, assuming all the code accessing the objects locks them before use. Be wary of [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), which often occur when locking multiple objects.

Comment: Note that a mutex is probably as big as two `float`s, so you’re probably not saving memory relative to some hypothetical solution based on copying.

Comment: Mutex(s) protect code paths not objects (variables) - this is a size effect of protecting one or more code paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote is fine, with one infamous caveat: you will deadlock if two threads try to take the same two locks but in opposite order.  This is illustrated by the classic [dining philosophers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) problem.

The standard solution is to impose some fixed, arbitrary order on the locks and take the “lower” one first in all cases.  user3290797’s answer provides the correct library facilities to use to do this.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(v1.guard_);
> std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(v2.guard_);
> ```

This way there is a risk of a deadlock if another thread tries to lock the same two mutexes in a different order.

In order to both avoid deadlocks and ensure exception safety, you need to first lock both mutexes at once, and then pass the already locked mutexes to `lock_guard`'s adopting constructors:

```
std::lock(v1.guard_, v2.guard_);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard1(v1.guard_, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard2(v2.guard_, std::adopt_lock);
```

In C++ 17 you can use `std::scoped_lock`, a class analogous to `std::lock_guard`, but capable of owning multiple mutexes:

```
std::scoped_lock guard{v1.guard_, v2.guard_};
```